# Why am I getting an Grpc.Core.RpcException when trying to get data from gRPC service written .net core

Tags: grpc-dotnet

I have a gRPC service (written in .net core 3.1) deployed in windows server as a self hosted service running in kerstel.

[image]
I added the below configuration to get the service running in https.

```
"Kestrel": {
"EndpointDefaults": {
  "Protocols": "Http2"
},
"Endpoints": {
  "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
    "Url": "https://hostname:8081",
    "Protocols": "Http2",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "path to .pfx file",
      "Password": "Super secret password"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the below code

```
using GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(httpsHost);
var client = new MyClient(channel);
var response = client.GetEntity(RequestCreator.GetRequest());
Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + response.ToString());
```

I get the an below exception and the inner exception is null.

> Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.")

[image]

Is there anything I should be adding to get the client to get the data from the service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response to my question. The problem was the proxy. What I ended up doing is create a webproxy, add the gRPC service URL to the bypassArrayList, create httpClientHandler, assigned the created proxy then create a httpClient that uses that httpClientHandler.

```
            var proxy = new WebProxy
            {
                Address = new Uri(proxyServer),
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
                Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            };

            proxy.BypassArrayList.Add(serviceUrl);

            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = proxy,
                DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                UseProxy = true,
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
            };

            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(serviceUrl, new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                HttpClient = client
            });
```